# What to do when Shia-Sunni conflict arises in an answer?

Tags: discussion, shia-sunni

Some times while answering a question, difference of source and narration between Shiism and Sunnism comes into effect. For example,  [the last sermon question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11647/last-sermon-a-companion-ask-a-question-that-if-we-could-not-understand-from-al) and [the successor to Muhammad](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11621/original-successor-of-muhammed) tends to end up with conflicts.

What is advisable in these type of situations?

Comment: Define conflict?

Comment: @BleedingFingers They have opposing narrations and sources, and that tends to lead to a **"I am correct you are wrong"** type of debate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume the place of the *"conflict"* being referred to is the comments section.

If non-constructive, mean, disrespectful, rude, offensive or vituperative argument or debate starts in the comments section. Or the answers are of that nature Request all parties *involved* to stop and be [civil and nice](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). Lead them to the [`[help/on-topic]`](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) which states:

> **Respect other people's beliefs**, and don't get into arguments about whether any particular group is "right" or "wrong"; we are all here to learn together.

And finally **do** flag the comment(s), and if there are plenty flag the entire post and inform the moderator in the *other*s section about it and they have the janitorial tool to make the place sparkling clean.

Furthermore, if the rude and offensive behavior continues they could be served suspensions from the site or worst case user deleted.

What's worth emphasizing is that comments should have constructive critiques within the scope in which the post is written and/or request for clarification.

> +1 [...]

and

> -1 [...]

should be [avoided](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/809/3175). And [Disagreement should not be a basis for down-voting](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/746/3487).

This site is for [learn](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)ing and sharing our knowledge about Islam, Q&A style.

Debates and protracted arguments should be taken to chat. But rules of civility remain intact. And should be

*Conflicts* have no place here or any other StackExchange sites.

Answer (score -2):

Like what wikipedia do. 
This is Shia view. 
This is Sunni view.