# Do we have to take advice from Shias and Sufis on this website?

Tags: discussion

Assalumu alykom warahmat allahi wa baraktuh (Peace be upon you) and Assaloto wa salamu aala sayedna wa habeebuna Muhammad ibnu abdullah, ama baad brothers and sisters (muslims) I have a question regarding the feasibility of asking questions here but receiving answers from Shia or Sufis and even Madakhilla and Ashaaira. If by chance they get to answer for some certain question that I asked and it might contradict the true sunnah of the rasool sallah allah aalyhee wa salam, can I have the right to downvote them and report their answers? I believe true muslims must follow the path of Rasool allah salla allah aalyhee wa salam and his sahaba al kiram and there is no doubt that many are misguided and have diverted their way from the true sunnah.

May Allah guide us all to the right path. Repent before its too late!!!!!!!!

Comment: Islam.SE is **not** exclusive to some specific sect or madhab of Islam. Sunnis, Shias, Sufis, Salafis, Asharis, Maturidis etc. everyone is welcome to ask questions and post answers. Voting must be based on the quality of the answer and not based on whether you agree or disagree with an individual's personal beliefs. See [Disagreement should not be a basis for down-voting](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/746/) , [Please vote based on quality](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/982/) etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend taking advice from *anyone* on this website without due diligence. There are literally no gatekeepers on who can answer questions, and "advice" in particular is so subjective that the StackExchange voting system is frankly terrible at differentiating *good* advice from *popular but bad* advice. The system works best when dealing with unambiguous objective facts rather than subjective opinions and advice, but even then you can't just assume any given answer is authoritative.

The quality of the answers you get is directly related to the quality of the question asked, and you need to make it clear when you ask your question *what you want in an answer*. If you need answers from any particular flavour of Islam, one that's *not* Shi'a or Sufi, *you need to specify that*.

As a moderator, I am unlikely to take any action on a flag when an answer clearly answers (or tries to answer) an unfocused question just because it's from the "wrong" flavour of Islam. However, I *would* likely take action if a question is clearly asking for answers from a particular perspective, and the answer is *clearly not written from that perspective*. The onus is on the questioner here to ask a good question, and on the community to determine the value of that question: vague unfocused questions are just going to get vague unfocused answers.

Welcome to StackExchange.